# Get Index of each  letter series from dictionary database

Tags: mysql, sql, algorithm, sql-server-2008

I have dictionary database and i have created one UI interface ,to place buttons alphabetically , on click of each Letter  , i want to fetch first word in the Letter series

Is there any trick or sql query by which i can list out, first word of each series against it's index

Note : i also have , Index column for each word in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SQL Server.

```
select ID,
       Word
from
  (
  select ID,
         Word,
         row_number() over(partition by left(Word, 1) order by Word) as rn
  from YourTable
  ) as T
where rn = 1
```

[SE-Data](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/77281)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
  word like '<letter>%'
```

ex:

```
word like 'a%'
word like 'b%'
```

Comment: But then i need to put all the letter from A to Z ? anything more shorter than that

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name
WHERE word LIKE 'a%';
```

Adding index on search column will help improve performance:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name add key ix1(word);
```

or using `REGEXP` you can search for multiple characters:

```
WHERE word REGEXP '^[a-d]';
```

Comment: but this will list only a series ,  i want  first word of each series against it's index